# VB.NET stringbuilder with length 256

Tags: vb.net, stringbuilder

I would like to create a stringbuilder with the length of 256, and the string "128" should be placed at the start.

However, my code

```
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    sb.Append(New String("128", 256))

    Dim s As String = sb.ToString
```

shows me that all 256 chars are filled with "1":

```
s = "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
```

Can somebody tell me what I did wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Your requirements aren't clear to me. Can you provide the expected output for sb.ToString?

Comment: You should Set Option Strict to ON, then this would not even compile instead of making wrong assumptions for you ("he wants to use the first char of the string, I guess")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm reading your question right, this should do what you want:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder(256)
sb.Append("128")
```

Or did you want spaces?

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder("128".PadRight(256))
```

The 256 in the StringBuilder constructor is a performance optimization. Since you know the length of the resulting string, go ahead and reserve all the space for it up front. It's also possible you'll be doing a lot more work to this string, such that a different (larger) number or no number may be appropriate there.

---

Based on the comment:

```
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder("128".PadRight(256, NullChar()))
```

But this is a really bad idea. Don't use nul characters in .Net.

Comment: I think he wants to repeat "128" over and over again until it fills 256 characters.

Comment: @vcsjones I don't know: he just said "at the start". I think he was hoping it would pad the string.

Comment: Well, I want "128" at the start and full up the rest with a NullChar (    Public Function NullChar() As Char

        Return Convert.ToChar(0)

    End Function)

Comment: @tmighty Just don't use Null characters in .Net. Really: don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

What you did wrong was *assume* what `New String("128", 256)` does. If you look at the nearest available constructor: [String Constructor (Char, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you will see it takes a Char. This means it ends up repeating the first char, `1`, 256 times.

The way you appear to want to do it could be realised using

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder("128")
sb.Length = 256
```

because according to the documentation on the [StringBuilder.Length Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "If the specified length is greater than the current length, the end of the string value of the current StringBuilder object is padded with the Unicode NULL character (U+0000)."